# Using SELECT within Trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

A customer needs a trigger for his new management tool. It works so far, but now he wants to get values from another table.

What does it mean? Take a short look at the (working) trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reldb_export_T_Import3_In
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON infor.RELDB
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE KST varchar(1000 BYTE);

  BEGIN

    IF (:new.ZUST = 4 AND :old.ZUST = 3 AND :old.SAINT = 60)
    THEN
      INSERT INTO infor2infoboard.T_Import3_In
        (Idx, Timestamp, ObjectId, Text, RowUid, GroupName, GroupIndex, PredTimeCondition, PredGapValue, Service, ReqQuan, ReqDur,
          Efficiency, BackColor, HighlightColor, Brightness, CellOffsetY, Fixed, Font, FontColor, Height, EarliestStart, LastDeliveryDate, RoleId,
          StatusIds, WithReservation, LastChange, LastEditedBy, Opacity, IsProcess, CheckSymbol, Link, Priority, IconPath, Adress, CA1, CA2,
          CA3, CA4, CA5, CA6, CA7, CA8, CA9, CA10, CA11, CA12, CA13, CA14, CA15, 
          CA16, CA17, CA18, CA19, CA20, CA21, CA22, CA23, CA24, CA25,
          CA26, CA27, CA28, CA29, CA30, CA31, CA32)
      VALUES
        (seq_t_import3_in.nextval, sysdate, :old.RNR, NULL, CASE WHEN :NEW.KST = '3710' THEN 'Pool TB-M 1;Pool TB-M 2;Pool TB-M 3;Pool TB-M 4;Pool TB-M 5' ELSE KST END, :old.Komm, NULL, NULL, NULL, :old.KTXT, :old.TA_4, NULL,
          NULL, CASE WHEN :new.MNR = '3740' THEN 'GREEN' WHEN :new.MNR != '3740' THEN 'BLUE' END, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, :old.TERM_2, :old.TERM_1, NULL, 
          NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
          NULL, SUBSTR(:old.ANR, 1, 10), :old.KOMM, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
          NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
          NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    END IF;......
```

Now he want to replace one of the last NULLS with a selected value.

The statement should look like this:

```
SELECT KTXT FROM RELDB WHERE ANR = :old.ANR and SAEXT = 'H';
```

So, for example:

```
NULL, (SELECT KTXT FROM RELDB WHERE ANR = :old.ANR and SAEXT = 'H';), SUBSTR(:old.ANR, 1, 10), :old.KOMM, NULL
```

My problem: I'm getting an error, that the trigger couldn't notice some changes. The trigger won't get fired.

So does anyone know how I can use or how I can get selected values (from the same (!!!) table which the trigger is listening to?

I'd appreciate your help :)

Cheers, 
Dom

Comment: Not very clear as what you need. Whats the error you are getting and is the trigger compiled

Comment: I'm able to compile it.
`(SELECT KTXT FROM RELDB WHERE ANR = :old.ANR and SAEXT = 'H'), SUBSTR(:old.ANR, 1, 10), :old.KOMM, NULL`

When I'm gonna start the triggered process, the following message pops up: ORA-04091: Table xxx is currently changing, Trigger/Function couldn't notice it (the changes). 
It's translated from GER, sorry^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you cannot select from the same table you are changing, this is the mutating table error.  See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:9579487119866

Comment: Hmm thought something like this, but wasn't sure at all. Thank you